# Is there a way to determine exactly when certain rows overlap with other row?

Tags: r, intervals

I have a data set of 3 columns: type (a and b), start time and end time. I need to see the first exact number that each type a row overlaps with all type b's. Here is an example of the data set. start and end time obviously represents seconds, and I want to know at what point type a's occurred during type b's. If anyone has any help on this that would be greatly appreciated!

structure(list(type = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b",
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), starttime = c(470, 858, 1330,
942, 1084, 1320, 1374, 1817, 1394, 1469, 1561, 1796, 1880, 1882,
508, 852, 1203, 1244, 1579, 1865, 2287, 3163, 3784, 4266, 4565,
4936, 5448), endtime = c(485, 873, 1345, 957, 1099, 1335, 1389,
1832, 1409, 1484, 1576, 1811, 1895, 1897, 536, 919, 1216, 1285,
1598, 1892, 2355, 3229, 3817, 4303, 4626, 4976, 5497)), row.names = c(NA,
-27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Instead of an image, can you use `dput` to share a sample of data? Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a great reproducible example in R. Also, if you could, provide additional information on what the end result would look like. A new data.frame? An additional column to the current data? This will help to better understand what is meant by: *the first exact number that each type a row overlaps with all type b's*. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ben thank you for replying. Ideally the end result would be a new data frame showing which type b the type an overlaps with, and when it does. For example the 2nd row (type a) overlaps with the 16th row (type b) at 858. Seeing all of those combinations in a new data frame would be ideal. I added the reproducible data in the question!

Comment: Thank you for providing the data. I added an answer below, though not sure if this provides the output you are looking for. Let me know.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this for 3 ranges at the same tine instead of two?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to approach multiple ranges to join on, but a lot depends exactly what the data looks like, and what you want as a desired outcome. Would this be the same as joining on overlapping ranges for 2 ranges, then taking that result and joining with a third range? I would recommend creating a new post/question with example data demonstrating with a small dataset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77869823/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-length-overlapping-lines-in-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment137289661_77869823 I posed this a few days ago, thought I would ask you if you knew of any way to do this!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77873616/3460670) that groups based on overlapping ranges. I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for (it would help if you can share your desired output, either as a final table or figure, even if you have to "make up" the results by hand). One potential issue is how you want to group there are 3 similar rows that overlap, and maybe a fourth that slightly overlaps with those 3 (in other words, how much overlap must exist to be considered part of the same group?). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of approaches that might help, depending on your exact needs. There are packages available that might offer methods worth trying out. These allow you to join or merge two different data sources with ranges.

One package is `fuzzyjoin` which uses "IRanges" from BiocManager. For example, using `interval_join`:

```
# install.packages("BiocManager")

# BiocManager::install("IRanges")

library(fuzzyjoin)

interval_join(df[df$type == "a",], 
              df[df$type == "b",], 
              by = c("starttime", "endtime"))
```

**Output**

```
  type.x starttime.x endtime.x type.y starttime.y endtime.y
  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a              858       873 b              852       919
2 a             1880      1895 b             1865      1892
3 a             1882      1897 b             1865      1892
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you Ben!