# How to group rows of a dataframe according to overlapping range columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(   chr = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11),   start = c(2530025, 431647, 1241413, 2891739, 4121824, 2324189),   end = c(2641128, 944232, 2446722, 2933803, 6426100, 3873886),   BP = c(2530025, 707496, 2159979, 2933803, 5226820, 3518621),   A1FREQ = c(0.001469300, 0.000689781, 0.000848240, 0.001410370, 0.004475170,
0.001768870),   N = c(22397, 22397, 22397, 22753, 22753, 22753),   SE = c(0.1363820, 0.1857480, 0.1685630, 0.1264720, 0.0739399, 0.1115480),   p = c(4.346403e-08, 9.899198e-11, 4.843954e-19, 2.158341e-09,
8.063062e-78, 1.348031e-27) )
```

I would like to create another column, called group, in which assigning a number. Rows with equal numbers are those showing overlapping start and end values.
Start and end numbers define a genomic range where the row/SNP lies. Therefore, I would like to assign the same number to SNPs/rows with overlapping genomic ranges, so with overlapping start and end columns. There is a way to do it in R?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's not as straight forward as it might seem. What if one location overlaps with more regions? Comma separated list of overlapping regions? That can get quite complex very quickly. There are packages specifically designed to do such tasks, e.g. `?IRanges::overlapsAny`, `?IRanges::overlapsRanges` or `?bedr::in.region`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the IRanges package through bioconductor can be helpful for objectives like these. It has a number of useful tools for those working in bioinformatics. Note that this requires installing "BiocManager" to install and setup.

The "IRanges" function creates an IRanges object containing ranges by start and end. The reduce function will group the ranges together based on overlap (in this example, into 3 ranges). The findOverlaps function finds overlaps between original data and these ranges. We then pull the subjectHits value which can serve as a group number.

```
# Install IRanges package
# https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html

# if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#   install.packages("BiocManager")

# BiocManager::install("IRanges")

library(IRanges)

ir <- IRanges(data$start, data$end)
data$group <- subjectHits(findOverlaps(ir, reduce(ir)))
```

**Output**

```
  chr   start     end      BP      A1FREQ     N        SE            p group
1  11 2530025 2641128 2530025 0.001469300 22397 0.1363820 4.346403e-08     2
2  11  431647  944232  707496 0.000689781 22397 0.1857480 9.899198e-11     1
3  11 1241413 2446722 2159979 0.000848240 22397 0.1685630 4.843954e-19     2
4  11 2891739 2933803 2933803 0.001410370 22753 0.1264720 2.158341e-09     2
5  11 4121824 6426100 5226820 0.004475170 22753 0.0739399 8.063062e-78     3
6  11 2324189 3873886 3518621 0.001768870 22753 0.1115480 1.348031e-27     2
```